# Searching LinkedList for a "Ingredient" and combining them

Tags: java, linked-list

Hey I currently have a certain linkedlist which contains all the ingredients that are available.

```
     private LinkedList<Ingredient> ingredients = new LinkedList<Ingredient>();
```

Ingredient contains the following values

```
ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Capsicum", 0.50, TOPPING));
ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Olives", 1.50, TOPPING));
ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Jalapenos", 1.00, TOPPING));
ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Beef", 2.75, TOPPING));
ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Pepperoni", 2.50, TOPPING));
```

It was going well until I had to return a String value that consists of more then 1 topping. My method of trying to find the toppings below.

```
public String toppings(){
    for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
        if (ingredient.hasType(Kitchen.TOPPING)){
            ingredients.add(ingredient);
            return ingredient.ingtoString();
        }
    }
    return "no toppings";
}
```

This only works for 1 ingredient that has been input and I'm not sure how I would fix it.

```
public String toppingFound(String topping){
    String s = "";
    s += " " + topping;
    return s;
}
```

this is the function that gets called by toppings()

so my question is, if it wasn't already clear is how I would modify is so that it would print multiple found ingredients instead of just the one.

Comment: an example is my code outputting this " Capsicum" when it should be outputting "Capsicum, Jalapenos, Beef"

Comment: Create a StringBuilder object in the method, append Strings to it as ingredients are found, and then return the StringBuilder's `toString()` result.

Comment: Or you could create an ArrayList within the method and at the end return a String built from this list, ... up to you as there are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I attempted to do that with my toppingFound method but I think I did something wrong

Comment: That method does nothing of use and is worthless. All it does is returns the String that is passed in and nothing more. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your method doesn't work:

```
for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
    if (ingredient.hasType(Kitchen.TOPPING)){
        ingredients.add(ingredient);
```

Here, I don't know why, you try to add the ingredient you found in the list of ingredients a second time to the end of the list

```
        return ingredient.ingtoString();
```

And here, you return immediately with the name of the first ingredient you found, instead of concatenating its name to the string you want to build.

A correct implementation would be

```
public String toppings() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
        if (ingredient.hasType(Kitchen.TOPPING)) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(", ");
            }
            builder.append(ingredient.ingtoString());
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

But the easiest way to do what you want nowadays is to use a stream:

```
String toppingIngredientNames = 
    ingredients.stream()
               .filter(i -> i.hasType(Kitchen.TOPPING))
               .map(Ingredient::ingtoString())
               .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Note: you should program on interfaces rather than implementations. The type of your variable should be `List<Ingredient>`, not `LinkedList<Ingredient>`. And you should choose ArrayList as the implementation, because LinkedList, in basically every reasonable use-case  you could imagine, is slower than LinkedList. (Deprecating LinkedList is being considered, BTW).

Comment: Streams look like a really interesting way of going about it. I think i'll so some research into them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder just like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels has said

> Create a StringBuilder object in the method, append Strings to it as ingredients are found, and then return the StringBuilder's toString() result.

here is the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
    if (ingredient.hasType(Kitchen.TOPPING)){
        sb.append(ingredient.ingtoString()).append(" ");
    }
}
//finally return as a String.
return sb.toString();
```